# Execution time of a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, execution-plan

I have a stored procedure and several statements in it. The below is execution time statistics of the procedure:

> SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time =
>   0 ms. SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed
>   time = 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 11484 ms,  elapsed time =
>   2277 ms.
>
> (29 row(s) affected)
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 11484 ms,  elapsed time =
>   2283 ms.

As you can see the total of 4562 ms. But when I look at the status bar I see that it took 2 seconds. I expect that it should be 4 seconds. Why are these two different?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` will give you summarized time results for a stored procedure in addition to time results for each query that's part of the stored procedure. Let's run a simple test to try to reproduce what you saw. The following code isn't important except that it runs for a few seconds on my machine:

```
set statistics time on;

WITH E00(N) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
        E02(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E00 a, E00 b),
        E04(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E02 a, E02 b),
        E08(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E04 a, E04 b),
        E16(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E08 a, E08 b),
        E32(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E16 a, E16 b),
   cteTally(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N) FROM E32)
SELECT AVG(CAST(N AS BIGINT)) 
FROM cteTally
WHERE N <= 10000000;

WITH E00(N) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
        E02(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E00 a, E00 b),
        E04(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E02 a, E02 b),
        E08(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E04 a, E04 b),
        E16(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E08 a, E08 b),
        E32(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E16 a, E16 b),
   cteTally(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N) FROM E32)
SELECT AVG(CAST(N AS BIGINT)) 
FROM cteTally
WHERE N <= 1000000;
```

Abbreviated output from `SET STATISTICS TIME ON`:

> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 3407 ms,  elapsed time =
>   3450 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 343 ms,  elapsed time = 388
>   ms.

As expected, there are two separate measurements for the execution time with the second query running in about one tenth of the time of the first. Now I'll create and run a stored procedure that just calls the above code. Abbreviated output from `SET STATISTICS TIME ON`:

> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 1187 ms,  elapsed time =
>   1201 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 110 ms,  elapsed time = 117
>   ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 1297 ms,  elapsed time =
>   1319 ms.

The math works out for my simple example: 1187 + 110 = 1297 CPU time and 1201 + 117 = 1319 elapsed time.